# JQuery Sortable PHP to Database

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

So I've got 2 boxes.  On the left I have a list of items pulling from the database which I can drag and drop to the right.  This works great.  I can't for the life of me work out how to get it to post the data for the list on the right and I think I've tried every example Google has to offer this week.

When I do a print_r($_POST); on the page this submits to, I get Array ( ) with nothing in it.  It doesn't seem to be grabbing the ID's and serializing them.

Does anyone have experience with this see anything I'm missing?

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "ul.droptrue" ).sortable({
        connectWith: "ul"
    });

    $( "ul.dropfalse" ).sortable({
      connectWith: "ul",
      dropOnEmpty: true
    });

    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).disableSelection();
  });

      $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    handle : '.handle', 
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        console.log(data);

        // POST to server using $.post or $.ajax
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'setlists-edit-process.php'
        });
    }
});

  </script>

<ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue">
<?php
$_GET['setlist_id'];
$sql = "SELECT material_id, material_name FROM material WHERE user_id=$session_id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
    exit();
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<li id=" . $row['material_id'] . ">" . $row['material_id'] . " | " . $row['material_name'] . "</li>";
}

?>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="dropfalse">

</ul>
```

Comment: What does your console.log(data) show?

Comment: setlists-edit.php?setlist_id=8:16 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
jquery.flot.js:711 Uncaught Invalid dimensions for plot, width = null, height = null

Comment: I would have thought it would be a parameter string?

Comment: Got rid of one of the errors.  console.log now shows:  function log() { [native code] }

Comment: [Check out serialize](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize) Also note that your id's for your `<li>` elements must contain an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<li id=" . $row['material_id'] . ">" . $row['material_id'] . " | " . $row['material_name'] . "</li>";
}
```

with:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<li id="material_' . $row['material_id'] . '">' . $row['material_id'] . " | " . $row['material_name'] . "</li>";
}
```

Sortable expects the ID to be in the format `setname_number`.

Moreover, your code outputs in the format `id=abc` (no quotations), and rather it should be `id="abc"` with surrounding quotes.

Comment: Thanks, it's now displaying the list items like this:  <li id="material_1" class="ui-sortable-handle">1 | Sawing a lady in half</li>.    The console still shows as:  function log() { [native code] }

Comment: @Topher can you try replacing `var data = $(this).sortable('serialize'); console.log( data );` with `var data = $("#sortable2").sortable('serialize'); var data2 = $("#sortable2").sortable('toArray'); console.log( 'Data Serialize:'); console.log( data ); console.log( 'Data toArray:'); console.log( data2 );`

Comment: Added.  What do I now do with it?

Comment: @Topher can you paste the results here? Do you still just see log(){ [native code] } ?

Comment: @Topher Oh, gosh! Your browser doesn't even have Console installed. Can you try replace `console.log()` with `alert()` in all instances? This will present a message box containing the variable.